# how to sum all variables data in php

Tags: php, function, variables

I need help to sum the total cost and display it in the report. I managed to multiply the quantity and cost but now how I can sum up the column that display the multiply?
below are the codes.

```
function inventory_summary($export_excel=0)
{
    $this->load->model('reports/Inventory_summary');
    $model = $this->Inventory_summary;
    $tabular_data = array();
    $report_data = $model->getData(array());
    foreach($report_data as $row)
    {
        $tabular_data[] = array($row['name'], $row['item_number'], $row['cost_price'], $row['quantity'], $Total_total=$row['quantity']*$row['cost_price']);
    }


    $data = array(
        "title" => $this->lang->line('reports_inventory_summary_report'),
        "subtitle" => '',
        "headers" => $model->getDataColumns(),
        "data" => $tabular_data,
        "summary_data" => $model->getSummaryData(array()),
        "export_excel" => $export_excel
    );

    $this->load->view("reports/tabular",$data); 
}
```

$Total_total this variable is data that extract from mysql database and multiply together, therefore is not saved in the database.

Added: Screenshot of the column I want to sum
Link: https://i.stack.imgur.com/WHaAm.png

Besides that how to display the Total column in decimal point? I search google high and low, but I unable to find any tutorial of adding decimal on sql result.

Appreciate any help that assist me in completing the report.
Thanks!

Comment: `$sum_total = $value_1+$value_2;` <= that will get you going. (*Peace*)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go

```
function inventory_summary($export_excel=0)
{
    $this->load->model('reports/Inventory_summary');
    $model = $this->Inventory_summary;
    $tabular_data = array();
    $report_data = $model->getData(array());

     $Totalprice=0;
        foreach($report_data as $row)
        {
        $Total_total=$row['quantity']*$row['cost_price'];
        $Total_total= number_format((float)$Total_total, 2, '.', '');
        $tabular_data[] = array($row['name'], $row['item_number'], $row['cost_price'], $row['quantity'],$Total_total );
        $Totalprice += $Total_total;
     }

    $tabular_data['Totalprice']=number_format((float)$Totalprice, 2, '.', '');


    $data = array(
        "title" => $this->lang->line('reports_inventory_summary_report'),
        "subtitle" => '',
        "headers" => $model->getDataColumns(),
        "data" => $tabular_data,
        "summary_data" => $model->getSummaryData(array()),
        "export_excel" => $export_excel
    );

    $this->load->view("reports/tabular",$data); 
}
```

Comment: I add this code    Total: <?php echo $Totalprice; ?> to the html and it's not working

Comment: where is your html ?? in your view you can see the total in the $data like `echo $data['Totalprice']` because you have assigned the tabular data in `"data" => $tabular_data` in your controller , you can view the total in controller after the loop like `echo $Totalprice;`

Comment: managed to display the result after changing the code to echo $data['Totalprice'] I need another help is how to display both total column and result in 2 decimal point?

Comment: Try this one `$tabular_data['Totalprice']=number_format((float)$Totalprice, 2, '.', '');`

Comment: thanks! @dianuj work like charm, but what code should I add for this    `$Total_total=$row['quantity']*$row['cost_price']` so that the total result column also show 2 decimal point?

Comment: thanks! @dianuj, can I have your email, I got a job on hand, which to source to someone give me your email so I can liaise with you at there.

Comment: here it is dianuj89@gmail.com

Answer (score 0):

You should `create` your `array` like,

```
function inventory_summary($export_excel=0)
{
    $this->load->model('reports/Inventory_summary');
    $model = $this->Inventory_summary;
    $tabular_data = array();
    $report_data = $model->getData(array());
    foreach($report_data as $row)
    {
       //create associative array here
       $tabular_data[]=array('name'=>$row['name'],'item_number'=>$row['item_number'],
                  'cost_price'=> $row['cost_price'],'quantity'=> $row['quantity']);
    }
    $data = array(
        "title" => $this->lang->line('reports_inventory_summary_report'),
        "subtitle" => '',
        "headers" => $model->getDataColumns(),
        "data" => $tabular_data,
        "summary_data" => $model->getSummaryData(array()),
        "export_excel" => $export_excel
    );

    $this->load->view("reports/tabular",$data); 
}
```

And at the time of showing `data` you can access every `array variable` by its `associative name`